# How can I determine the manufacturer of my diverter?

Tags: shower

I'm currently experiencing the same situation as this post:[how-do-i-prevent-this-bath-faucet-from-leaking-while-the-shower-is-running](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/22052/how-do-i-prevent-this-bath-faucet-from-leaking-while-the-shower-is-running) My bath faucet's lever to redirect the water to overhead shower does not fully stop the water.

My plumber is having a difficult time determining the manufacturer to be able to order the nozzle. What are some ways to determine the maker of the nozzle?

Asking since I can't just replace it with the standard chrome or brushed metal ones. My current nozzle is gold-plated (or gold-painted) and the wife would like its replacement to match. Therefore, I need to know the maker to be able to order the part.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about getting the exact one. Even if you could find the make/model, who knows if they still make it or if it is identical (designs change over the years).  go find something similar that your wife likes and install it.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the manufacturer/model could be difficult.  Is [This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RMFVOK) close enough?  Or
[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NN75DY)?